# translation of 2 squares using openGL

Tags: opengl, graphics

I am creating 2 squares. I want translate the 2 squares one after the another.
for example: 1st square should move to certain position and after that 2nd square should move.

Note: both the squares are created first then we have to move them one by one.

If any of you want the code i can mail you the code also. i am not able to upload it here.

Comment: OpenGL has practically nothing to do with animation. It just renders stuff to a surface. Animating things is entirely the responsibility for your code, or some kind of animation framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef( square[0].x, square[0].y, 0.0f );
DrawSquare( square[0] );
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef( square[1].x, square[1].y, 0.0f );
DrawSquare( square[1] );
glPopMatrix();
```